# WooCommerce - require php file for specific category

Tags: templates, woocommerce

I'm trying to add :

require get_template_directory() . '/mytheme/folder/file.php';

To specific category in WooCommerce, I tried already:

```
function get_file() {
if( has_term( 'categoryName', 'product_cat' ) )  {
require get_template_directory() . '/mytheme/folder/file.php';
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'get_file');
```

But it doesen't work ;/
How can i add this file only for 1 category?
Or for multi cat. by using else if
Regards, Gabrielle

Comment: Is this a template file or is it serving some other purpose?

Comment: I try uplad file to my WooCommerce shop, for price validation, but only specific file to specific category

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you aren't getting a PHP error for the file not existing. But check out the [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) function. It gives you the path to the current theme folder. Therefore I think your path is probably wrong since your theme folder is being repeated... something akin to `SOME_PATH_STUFF/wp-content/themes/mytheme/mytheme/folder/file.php`

Try the following instead:

```
function get_file() {
if( has_term( 'categoryName', 'product_cat' ) )  {
require get_template_directory() . '/folder/file.php';
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'get_file');
```