# WooCommerce: how to include PHP files from WC pages?

Tags: woocommerce

From my WC pages (`shop`, `product`, etc) I need to manually include a PHP file located at my theme's root folder. However `include('my_file.php');` triggers a `failed to open stream...` error if I do it from any WC page such as `Shop`.

How can I make such includes ?

Comment: Don't forget that when you do an `include` of a filename on its own it will look for that file in the same folder as the script calling the include... E.g. if you have your `index.php` in your `httpdocs` root folder and it calls `include('file.php')` then that file should also reside in your `httpdocs`... otherwise you will receive the `failed to open stream...` error. Have a read: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27888865/383847)